# How to use a block of input and pipe it with time offset

Tags: powershell, citrix

I am currently working on automating a minor step for our Citrix environment. I am working with a few SDKs from Citrix, but they are not relevant for the question.

Right now I use the following block:

```
Get-BrokerMachine -PowerState Off -DesktopGroupName * -InMaintenanceMode $False | New-BrokerHostingPowerAction -Action TurnOn
```

This powers all machines on our delivery controller, that are turned off, not in maintenance mode and are assigned to any Delivery Group.

Sadly, this raises the problem that, once more than 30-50 machines are not powered, our network is shortly throttled because 30-50 machines boot 100GB images.

I therefore tried the following:

```
$Machines = Get-BrokerMachine -PowerState Off -DesktopGroupName * -InMaintenanceMode $False
Foreach ($Machine in $Machines) {
New-BrokerHostingPowerAction -Action TurnOn
Start-Sleep -s 120 }
```

My question is, because I can not reliable test this: Does the loop work like this? Am I missing something? The goal is offset the boots, so after every boot the script waits 120 seconds before booting the next one.

Comment: Looks good to me. As for a test, try a small sample `foreach($m in $machines[0..2]) {...}` to process only a few items instead of the whole list.

Comment: I will try this, once we face said boot error again and some machines are offline. Has not happened the past 4 days, but let us see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks good to me too. 

You can always replace `New-BrokerHostingPowerAction -Action TurnOn`  with  ` write-host "$(Get-Date)" ` as a test

Also how long does boot normally take? Do you know the IP or hostname of the broker host? You could do a connection test for latency and use that to throttle the boot up process rather than doing a default start-sleep. The issue I see with start-sleep -s 120 is you said 30 to 50 machines which means boot could take anywhere from an hour to 2.

Comment: So the initial idea was a scheduled task with said posh script, once initialized at around 4am, and once 6am. Twice to make sure every machine is booted. I like the write-host idea, also thought about outputting a ping or something similar to a txt to log if a machine did not boot. Due to the fact I have both the DNS and IP, this should be no problem. Thanks for your input too!

Comment: @Bowshock take a look at the answer to the question here - you can try a similar approach to turn on in batches of let's say 10-20 at a time (depending on network performance). That way you don't have to wait so long for the process to complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948182/how-to-pause-a-foreach-powershell-loop